# Installscript project how to hook into the install process

Tags: installation, installshield, installscript

I have created an installscript project using InstallShield 2010. I gather info during the install process in the method "OnFirstUIBefore()". But when the actual install of the software is happening (i.e. when you see a progress bar and it is copying over installation files) I would like to do some actions based on the user input.

My 2 questions are:

1 - How do I hook into that actual part of the install process?

2 - If any issues arise, how would I then undo what I have done?

Note :- this is a pure installscript project, not an installscript MSI project etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the custom actions in Custom Action and Sequences...